# Can't find Hibernate's SessionFactory in my Glassfish app server

Tags: hibernate, orm, glassfish, jndi, sessionfactory

I'm just playing around with implementing Hibernate as persistence provider in Glassfish application server. I already configured JNDI datasource, connection pool etc. My Hibernate config is as follows:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/myDatasource</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.factory_class">net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">hibernateSessionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="org.me.jsf.entities.Node" />
      </session-factory>    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I try to use Session Factory this way:

```
    try {  
        sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) new InitialContext()
                .lookup("hibernateSessionFactory");  
    } catch (Throwable ex) {  
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);      
    }
```

I get an exception "ExceptionInInitializerError", caused by, according to the logs,  "Lookup failed for 'hibernateSessionFactory'". But when I use this code:

```
    try {    
         AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
         cfg.configure();
         sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {  
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  
    }
```

...everything goes fine.

What I got wrong here? I even tried to make an entry for managed bean hibernateSessionFactory for relevant class in faces-config.xml, but still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence of `hibernate.session_factory_name` means that session factory will be bound to JNDI when created, but you still to execute a code that creates it during startup. From [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-jndi):

> Hibernate will automatically place the SessionFactory in JNDI after you call cfg.buildSessionFactory(). This means you will have this call in some startup code, or utility class in your application, unless you use JMX deployment with the HibernateService (this is discussed later in greater detail).

Comment: So basically, to use code similar to faulty one, I must configure Hibernate as Glassfish's JMX?

Comment: @DoktorNo: I'm not familiar with JMX. However, you can use this code if you call `buildSessionFactory()` in the startup code, for example, in `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try ServletContextListener, but still I am looking for solution, that is solely based on application server, so  JMX is an option.